# How to diagnose fault in crashing UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, crash

I have a UWP application which runs fine from Visual Studio with the debugger attached. If I run the app standalone, from the start menu - which is the app that Visual Studio has deployed - it will start, but crash when I invoke one of the functions in the app.

UWP provides absolutely no information - the window disappears and I get the following in the Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: MyApp.Uwp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5c889173
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.18362.207, time stamp: 0x36bacadb
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0086b264
Faulting process id: 0x27f4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d53db7eaba0778
Faulting application path: C:\src\MyApp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\MyApp.Uwp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: 009e5859-3f05-4790-8072-37af666acb7e
Faulting package full name: 59640b3f-2209-4686-8f9a-9f8748b9753c_1.0.0.0_x86__9617mk99wz2v0
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

If I start the app via the Start menu, then attach the VS debugger, it doesn't crash.

How can I get a stack trace and work out what is going wrong here?

Comment: *but crash when I invoke one of the functions in the app*, Please share more detail about this function. And the better way is that provide [mcve].

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I found the cause of the problem before I posted this question. It's intentionally vague to help others in this situation. I want to know if it's possible to get a stack trace or any information out of a crashed UWP app.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if it's possible to get a stack trace or any information out of a crashed UWP app.

You could use **HockeyApp** to capture the exception call stack, exception message, exception type name, file name and line number which caused a crash in the app. For more detail please refer this [document](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/crash-reporting-for-uwp).

**Please note**: In order to symbolicate crashes for .NET UWP applications you need to upload symbol (*.pdb) files

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know Hockey / AppCenter can be used for this; is it possible to get this information from a stock app on the OS without integrating with third party software?

Comment: I think you could use try catch to capture the exception and write the error to the local storage.